# android ext4 file deletion / recovery without utilities

Tags: android, ext4, computer-forensics

i´m trying to find a way how to delete and restore files in android - not using android file explorer tools or external tools for forensic analysis.
So far i understand that most devices has ext4 file system and that erased data still exist, only metadata are deleted.
I´ve read few articles about forensic analysis but they all use tools. 
I guess i have to use Adb shell and find a header of the file and alter it, but haven´t found any explanation how. 
Am i heading right direction or wrong ? Any help appreciated.
(I have one rooted and not rooted device, both higher than 5.0 Android)

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you will need to use tools.   Consider the question, "I want to hammer a nail into mahogany without using tools?"   How would you answer that question?   A hammer is the natural instrument one would us to accomplish the task.   But it's a tool.   I suppose you could use a rock, but technically speakinng, that's also why a tool.   It's why we talk about prehistoric humans as being tool users, even if they are using tools made out of an axe.

In this particular case, you'll want to take a full image backup of the disk partition which will require root, and then use a program like photorec to recover the deleted files.

Comment: appreciate comment, but even tools have their way how to do it. In my case, im trying to make one of the tools specific function (restore deleted file / delete file), yet, I couldnt find anything helpful.